# C3 CSS has .c3 path and .c3 line statement yet still shows black space on line graph

Tags: css, c3.js

[Basic C3 graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nJbq.png). I have a basic C3 line graph to be used in a demo that has black space appear any time the points intersect. Graph shows up fine and functionality works, its just the black spaces that i can not figure out. Looking for any additional solutions. I am using bootstrap 3 with associated CSS as well in this project

Downloaded C3 and referenced the css and js in my html doc. Made sure that the CSS file had the below referenced .c3path code as was mentioned in prior questions and the issue still presents itself.

```
.c3 path, .c3 line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
```

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['SUDT MEDS', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['NON-SUDT MEDS', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ],

    }

});
```

```
<link href="$SOURCE_DIR$\JS\C3-0.7.5\c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media=all />
```

No error messages.

Comment: What exactly did you mean by black space?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the graph to give better idea, rather then try to poorly explain it. Hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is the css file isn't getting picked up at all. That $SOURCE_DIR$  - is this something that gets parsed in php or in a templating system as otherwise that's not a valid filepath.

Answer (score 0):

I think your path is not correct. I assume you are using PHP and html,  try to use

```
<?php 
$SOURCE_DIR = 'your_path';
?>
//etc
<a href="<?php $SOURCE_DIR;?>/JS/C3-0.7.5/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media=all />
```

with forwarding slash